# Как проверить установлен ли git в скрипте

Tags: bash, shell

Я пишу скрипт и мне нужно осуществить проверку установлен ли git. Я делаю переменную git_check=$(git --version) и потом пытаюсь ее сверить со строчкой command not found, но ничего не получается. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: `which git` и проверить код выхода

Comment: Переносимо или нет? С наличием дополнительных пакетов или нет? Больше условий!

Comment: Если такой команды нет, то `git --version` завершится с ненулевым кодом, вот и вся проверка.

Comment: @user7860670, а если это скрипт вида `exit 0`? Откуда вы знаете список просматриваемых путей? Короче, не так всё просто.

Comment: @andreymal, `which git` выдаёт мне `/home/user/bit/git`, а там просто скрипт вида `exit 0`. Ваши действия?:

Comment: @0andriy никаких действий, это уже личные проблемы пользователя

Comment: Мне помогло which git | grep "git" ...
Спасибо всем за помощь